# Badge notifications from other sites should not use the icons from the current site

Tags: bug, design, badges, notifications

Badge notification from other sites (here, meta.SE) should use their resp. badge icons (here, the default), not the ones from the site I'm currently on.

Failing that (because, do we really want to load *all* the icons?), use the default icons in notifications.

[image]
[image]

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks! Searching is _still_ impossible here... T_T